# install latest tensorflow version on Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I installed Anaconda today and added the tensorflow package. On Anaconda, the tensorflow version is 1.1.0. The current tensorflow version on tensorflow.org is 1.8.0. So I followed the installation guideline found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_anaconda

It seemed to went well and I got a successful install message as shown below:
Successfully installed absl-py-0.2.0 astor-0.6.2 bleach-1.5.0 gast-0.2.0 grpcio-1.11.0 html5lib-0.9999999 markdown-2.6.11 numpy-1.14.3 protobuf-3.5.2.post1 setuptools-39.1.0 six-1.11.0 tensorboard-1.8.0 tensorflow-1.8.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.14.1 wheel-0.31.0

However, on Anaconda, it still shows tensorflow version as 1.1.0. How do I update it to 1.8.0 for tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try the anaconda cloud?

https://anaconda.org/aaronzs/tensorflow-gpu